# Open certain amount of files by glob

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use `glob`to open excel file in one folder and then `concat` them into 1 file but it takes quite a long time to open all files and then concat like that (each file contents around 20000 rows).

So I would like to ask is there anyway to open certain amount of files using glob? Ex: Recent 30 files in all files. Or is there another way to make it

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is there another way to make it

I generally deal with this by using the os method `listdir` to list all available files in a given directory (*e.g.* `path_to_files`),  then open them using the pandas `read_csv` or `read_excel` method and append them to a `list_of_dataframes` to concatenate:

```
import os 
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path_to_files = Path('...') #The path to the folder containing your excel files

list_of_dataframes = []
for myfile in os.listdir(path_to_files):
     pathtomyfile = path_to_files / myfile
     list_of_dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(pathtomyfile)) 

df=pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
```

The number of files to load can be specified by indexing, *e.g.* for the last 30 files:

`for myfile in os.listdir(path_to_files)[-30:]`

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this code for merging mp4 files but of course you could use this with other files

```
from glob import iglob

def enumerate_files(source: str, ext: str = "*") -> Iterator[str]:
   """Enumerate and scan the files from folder by given extension"""
   return iglob(os.path.join(source, f"*.{ext}"))

def combine_files(source: str, output: str,ext: str = "mp4") -> None:
   folder = join(os.getcwd(), source)
   with open(output, "wb") as wb:
      for file in enumerate_files(folder, ext):
          with open(file, "rb") as fd:
              shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wb)
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion :D

Answer (score 0):

If there is a certain naming convention you could select files that only meet a certain requirement? as:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('*criteria*)
```

or you could get the list and then split the list of files into n subsets?

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('*xlx')
length = len(listfiles)
center = length//2

a = listfiles[:center]
b = listfiles[center:]
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion :D